# Class library with different version of a nuget package in another project

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget

I made a class library with RestSharp 108.0.1 installed. I added this class library to another solution simply with rightclick on the soloution - add - existing project and added it to the references. This solution uses RestSharp version 107.3.0.

The project compiles, but when I start it, I get the error "could not load file or assembly RestSharp, Version=108.0.1.0...."

The project tries to load the RestSharp Version of the class library, but cannot find it because it only has the version 107.3.0. When I update it to the same version, it works. But thats not a possible solution, because the class library should be used among different projects and I cannot keep all in sync all the time.

Is there a possibility to make the nuget-package version of the class library independent to the projects where it is implemented?

Thank you!

Comment: what if theres a breaking change? .net doesn't have a good story for isolating dependencies

Comment: Please give us more information. Just adding a project to a solution doesn't make any other projects depend on it. Usually the highest version of a library is used when an application depends on multiple projects which each depend on the same library. That's generally okay, so long as there aren't breaking changes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added it to the references too

Comment: The references of what *precisely* though? Again, the details really matter. If you could be absolutely concrete about this, it would be easier to help you. It would also help if you'd tell us what project style you're using - SDK-style projects are much simpler in terms of versioning, in my experience.

Comment: It's really hard to explain. I'm using a class library "EloLoader" which has implemented RestSharp 108.0.1.0 and multiple WPF projects which are referencing to the class library "EloLoader". One of those WPF projects has RestSharp version 107.3.0 already implemented. When calling the class library, the WPF project tries to load RestSharp 108.0.1.0 because "EloLoader" uses it, but can't find it because it only has 107.3.0